# I've created a slideshow using ViewPager, need to make a 3 small changes but stuck

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I wanted to create a simple slideshow. I've gotten reasonably far, but now I'm stuck, I'm sure my issues sound very simple to you guys, hence why I'm here looking for help :-) I have made an effort, source code below.

**Changes I'm stuck on**

1. I want the images of the slideshow to fill the screen
2. I also don't want the user to have to drag the image across, I just want him to tap the image and it goes to the next one.
3. When the slideshow ends (reaches last item, a toast message tells user its finished)

I have tried to do the above, but like I said. I'm abit new at all this

ImagePager:

```
public class ImagePager extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArra );
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myimagepager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }


    private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, 
                                R.drawable.five,R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight,
                                R.drawable.nine,R.drawable.ten,R.drawable.eleven, R.drawable.twelve,

                                };

public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    int imageArray[];

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
        imageArray = imgArra;
        activity = act;
        }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageArray.length;}

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);   

        ImageView im=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myimage);             
        im.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout, 0);
           return layout;   
           }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
        }
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slide, menu);
    return true;
    }

   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.test.demo.SETTING");
        startActivity(p);
    break;
    }

return false;
}
   }
```

Slide:

```
public class Slide extends Activity {   
    public int currentimageindex=0;
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask task;
    ImageView slidingimage;

    private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
            R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six,
            R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.nine,
            R.drawable.ten, R.drawable.eleven, R.drawable.twelve,

            };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
     // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow();              
            }
        };

        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

             mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        }

        }, delay, period);             

    }      

    private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        boolean animation_one = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_one", false);
        boolean animation_two = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_two", false);    
        boolean animation_three = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_three", false);
        boolean animation_four = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_four", false);
        boolean animation_five = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_five", false);              

     if (animation_one == true) {   
        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
        currentimageindex++;
        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);               
          slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

    }else if (animation_two == true) {
        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
        currentimageindex++;
        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);       
          slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

    }else if (animation_three == true) {
        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
        currentimageindex++;
        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);       
          slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

    }else if(animation_four == true) {
        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
        currentimageindex++;        
        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move);        
          slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

    }else if (animation_five == true) {
        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
        currentimageindex++;
        Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);       
          slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  

    }else if(animation_one == false && animation_two == false && animation_three == false 
            && animation_four == false && animation_five == false){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Slide.this, ImagePager.class);                                     
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slide, menu);
        return true;
        }

       @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent p = new Intent("com.test.demo.SETTING");
            startActivity(p);
        break;
        }

    return false; 
    }
             }
```

Setting:

```
public class Setting extends PreferenceActivity {

    CheckBoxPreference animation_one;
    CheckBoxPreference animation_two;
    CheckBoxPreference animation_three;
    CheckBoxPreference animation_four;
    CheckBoxPreference animation_five;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);

        animation_one = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("animation_one");
        animation_two = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("animation_two");       
        animation_three = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("animation_three");
        animation_four = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("animation_four");
        animation_five = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("animation_five");


        animation_one.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                Object newValue) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            animation_one.setChecked(true);
                            animation_two.setChecked(false);
                            animation_three.setChecked(false);
                            animation_four.setChecked(false);
                            animation_five.setChecked(false);

                            return true;
                        }

                    });         
        animation_two.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                Object newValue) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            animation_one.setChecked(false);
                            animation_two.setChecked(true);
                            animation_three.setChecked(false);
                            animation_four.setChecked(false);
                            animation_five.setChecked(false);

                            return true;

                        }

                    });         
                            /////
                            animation_three.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                        Object newValue) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    animation_one.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_two.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_three.setChecked(true);
                                    animation_four.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_five.setChecked(false);

                                    return true;
                                }

                            });       
                    animation_four.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                        Object newValue) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    animation_one.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_two.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_three.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_four.setChecked(true);
                                    animation_five.setChecked(false);

                                    return true;
                                }

                            });       

                            animation_five.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                        Object newValue) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    animation_one.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_two.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_three.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_four.setChecked(false);
                                    animation_five.setChecked(true);

                                    return true;
                                }

                            });       

           }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what your trying to do is capture a touch event that will page to the next item without actually "scrolling" this works in contrast to how a ViewPager was intended to work. More often than not a ViewPager will be set up with fragments and a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to switch between fragments when scrolling.

If you want to be able to scroll back and forth without fragments you will need to assign an OnPageChangeListener for your view pager and handle the event callbacks within that interface to viewPager.setSelectedItem(intPostion) when handling the event. (This can get complicated due to capturing the physics of the touch event, velocity, etc)

For your slideshow example I would simply not use a view pager but have an activity with two buttons, left and right, and a container layout that will switch out various fragments when the button is click (along with playing all your cool animations in between).

To pull that off you will need to store your drawable references or images in some type of array or ArrayList to keep track of the current position. Also you will want to put checks for the left and right buttons to only go to the next/previous item if there is an items to switch to.